# Set parameter for Doctrine filter on every request in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, filter, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a Doctrine filter in Symfony2 project. I am trying to set filter's parameter to some value (taken from session) on every request.
The problem is that filter object is created after Symfony's onKernelRequest event, so I can't set it from there. If I try to set it in Doctrine's postConnect event circular dependency is detected:

```
ServiceCircularReferenceException: Circular reference detected for service "doctrine.orm.private_entity_manager", path: "routing.loader -> assetic.asset_manager -> twig -> translator.default -> doctrine.orm.private_entity_manager -> doctrine.dbal.private_connection -> year_visibility.parameter_setter".
```

The question is, where (or rather how) should I set filter's parameter?

Answer (score 5):

You can try to define filters manually and pass required parameters at the same time.

```
services:
    app.filter_manager:
        class: App\Bundle\AppBundle\Filter\FilterManager
        arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager, @session]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
```

And in the filter manager class:

```
// ...

public function __construct(EntityManager $em, SessionInterface $session) 
{
    $this->em = $em;
    $this->session = $session;
}

// ...

public function onKernelRequest()
{
    $this->em->getConfiguration()->addFilter('filter_name', 'Filter/Class/Name/With/Ns');

    $filter = $this->em->getFilters()->enable('filter_name');
    $filter->setParameter('param_name', $this->session->get('param_name'));
}
```

Comment: I think this wouldn't work, because the `FilterCollection` instanciates the Filter class without using the service container.

Answer (score 2):

As seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14650403/244058 ,

you can have an instance of your Filter class at kernel boot.
So, your instance would be available **very** early.

```php
<?php

class MyBundle extends Bundle 
{
    public function boot()
    {
        $em = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager');
        $conf = $em->getConfiguration();
        $conf->addFilter(
            'filter_name',
            'Doctrine\Filter\TestFilter'
        );

        // either enable it here, or later in the event listener
        $em->getFilters()->enable('filter_name');
    }
}
```

After that, just add a kernel.event_listener that listens on `kernel.request` and set a filter parameter (something like this):

```php
<?php

class DoctrineSqlFilterConfigurator
{
    private $em; // inject the entity manager somehow (ctor is a good idea)

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $filter = $this->em->getFilters()->enable('filter_name');
        $filter->setParameter('param_name', $event->getRequest()->getSession()->get('param_name'));
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem now is, that when onKernelRequest is triggered by internal sub request, it says the filter does not exist.

Comment: When does it says that ? Do you have the stack trace?

Comment: Twig_Error_Runtime: An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Filter 'filter_name' does not exist.") in "DefaultBundle:Template:index.html.twig" at line 30.

Comment: I guess it is from Twig because internal sub request is made by using Twig's render functionality.

Comment: It's also strange that other queries are made as if filter was not loaded except they do not throw error...

Comment: Are you sure about the filter name ? have you really named it `filter_name` ?

Comment: No it's 'year_visibility', but how does this make a difference?

Comment: if you named it `year_visibility`, you have to enable `year_visibility`. sorry, it's obvious so I maybe don't get what you mean :)