# Symfony2 - Create a Doctrine filter to select current user data

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, multi-tenant, saas

I'm building a Saas / Multitenant application using Symfony 2. I've created a Doctrine event-subscriber to add and update the owner of a row, the user who created it, the user who modified it, timestamps and so.

And now I need to implement some kind of filter so when a user is logged in, he only can see data from his company. My first though was using a Doctrine preLoad event, but this event doesn't exist... As far as I know, I must use Doctrine filters, isn't it? If so, how can this filter access user data to read the company id? Must I inject it using the Dependency Injection? Is there any standard way to accomplish my goal?

**UPDATE**
What I'm looking for is to create some kind of Doctrine plugin/hook so everytime I call any function that fetch data from the database (find, findOneBy, etc), and the entity I'm fetching implements a particular interface, an extra 'AND company_id=:id' SQL sequence is added to the generated query, so neither the controller or the model receives data from other companies.

Comment: maybe this answer can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15809800/3059764

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this you can use a DoctrineFilter
Link from official doc [Doctrine2 SQL Filters](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/filters.html)

```
namespace Rwmt\Bundle\RwmtBundle\DoctrineFilters;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetaData,
    Doctrine\ORM\Query\Filter\SQLFilter;

class MultiTenantFilter extends SQLFilter
{
    public function addFilterConstraint(ClassMetadata $targetEntity, $targetTableAlias)
    {
        // Check if the entity implements the MultiTenant interface
        if (!$targetEntity->reflClass->implementsInterface('Rwmt\Bundle\RwmtBundle\Entity\MultiTenant')) {
            return "";
        }

        return $targetTableAlias.'.tenant_id = ' . $this->getParameter('tenantId');
    }
}
```

And to set the parameter tenantId used in the filter you must enable the filter and set the parameter

```
$filter = $em->getFilters()->enable('multi_tenant');
$filter->setParameter('tenantId', $tenant->getId(), 'integer');
```

As for the MultiTenant interface is just something for the entities to implement

```
namespace Rwmt\Bundle\RwmtBundle\Entity;
use Rwmt\Bundle\RwmtBundle\Entity\Tenant;

interface MultiTenant
{
    public function setTenant(Tenant $tenant);
    public function getTenant();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Filtering in Doctrine2 is simple.  Just assign a filter function to a variable, then send that variable as a parameter through the filter() method included in the ArrayCollection class.

```
$closure = function($list_item) use($user) {                                
        return $list_item->belongsToSameCompanyThatEmploys($user) === true;
};                                                         
$filtered_array_collection = $arrayYouWantToFilter->filter($closure);
```

In this example, you'd have to have previously defined a method `belongsToSameCompanyThatEmploys($user)` in list_item's class that returns `true` if it belongs to the same company that the user works for.

`UPDATE` You need to also indicate that the filter function should use the local variable  user, since it won't otherwise due to having its own scope.

Comment: I'm not sure if we're talking about the same... I need a filter that alters the SQL command before sending it to the server (add a simple 'AND company_id=:id'), and link this filter with symfony, so at each request the filter uses the current logged user company_id...

Comment: Oh I see. Indeed we are talking about different things!  I was answering how to filter after receiving all rows.

Comment: @iamadev: this is exactly what I want to avoid, to receive all rows and then filtering them. I want them to be filtered in the database engine, not in PHP.