# Could doctrine provide records filtered by user roles, groups or permissions?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I've a project with a huge amount of data. I need to make query based on user role/group/permission. This means that a query like

```
$fooRepository = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getManager()
    ->getRepository(Foo::class)
    ->findAll();
```

should return different records if done by a ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN or by  ROLE_USER. Also, I need to filter record based on relations and so on.

I've different solution in mind:

- inject user role inside the repository's query
- create a role based repository
- create a query for each role

### Inject user role in repository's query

In this case each repository should be responsible to provide right data. This is a solution similar [to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23747697/symfony2-create-a-doctrine-filter-to-select-current-user-data). In that solution record are filtered by tenant.

### Create role based repository

In this case I'll need to create different repositories and instantiate them differently. But I don think this can be easy in doctrine? while I am writing, ... I am thinking this is an exaggerated solution.

### Create queries for each roles

At the moment I think this is the more natural way to do queries. I just imagine that a repository should contain

```
+ findAllStuffForGuestRole()
+ findAllStuffForAdminRole()
```

Each time I need to add a query, I MUST create different queries.

Comment: why you can't create method findAllStuffByRole(ROLE) ? this is optimal method. Also, there is such thing as http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/filters.html

Comment: I think the solution with doctrine filters are the best and the simplest way to solve your problem. Do you see any contraindications to use them?

Comment: @miikes thak you. Filter could be a very clean and good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [Doctrine filters](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/filters.html) are the cleanest and the simplest way to solve your problem. See the [documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/filters.html)

Comment: I dont know if filters are the best one. But its great solution.

Answer (score -1):

This is actually very straight forward with Symfony/Doctrine. Here's a great page in the official docs that explains it better than I could: http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/repository.html